# I am doing an assignment that asks me to make a function that creates an acronym from a string, then return the acronym

Tags: c, substring, c-strings, uppercase, function-definition

The prompt that I'm given is: An acronym is a word formed from the initial letters of words in a set phrase. Write a program whose input is a phrase and whose output is an acronym of the input. If a word begins with a lower case letter, don't include that letter in the acronym. Assume there will be at least one upper case letter in the input.

Also, I am given the following function to use: void CreateAcronym(char userPhrase[], char userAcronym[]).

My problem with the code is that only the first letter is being saved to the userAcronym variable.
For example, when the string is Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers. The output I'm getting is just I. What do I need to change to get the remaining letters?

Thank you for the help.

My code so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #define MAX 60

     void CreateAcronym(char userPhrase[], char userAcronym[]){
       int i;
   
   
       int j=0;
       for(i = 0; i < strlen(userPhrase); ++i){
       if(isupper(userPhrase[i])){
     
       userAcronym[j]=userPhrase[i];
       }
       j++;
       }
       printf("%s", userAcronym);
     }

     int main(void) {
     char phrase[MAX];
     char acronym[10];
   
     fgets(phrase, MAX, stdin);
     CreateAcronym(phrase, acronym);
   

     return 0;
     }
```

Comment: One problem is the fact that your input array is 60 characters long, and your output array is 10 characters long.  That's just begging for a buffer overflow.

Comment: You need to increase `j` *inside* the `isupper` block.

Comment: And add a null character at the end.

Comment: @EmanuelP Do you mean to do the following?
         if(isupper(userPhrase[i])){
         userAcronym[j]=userPhrase[i];
         j++;
         printf("\0");
      }

Comment: @Ale Almost. When the loop is ended, you should do `userAcronym[j] = '\0'` This will make it a zero-terminated string. The `printf` was in the right place. It should be just before that.

Comment: @EmanuelP Thank you, I was able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function `CreateAcronym` should be declared at least like

```
void CreateAcronym( const char userPhrase[], char userAcronym[]);
```

because the passed string that contains a phrase is not being changed within the function.

But it will be even better to declare the function like

```
char * CreateAcronym( const char userPhrase[], char userAcronym[]);
```

The function should not output anything. It is the caller of the function that decides whether to output the acronym formed within the function.

The function invokes undefined behavior because the array acronym does not get a string.

Moreover there is another bug in the for loop

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(userPhrase); ++i){
   if(isupper(userPhrase[i])){
       userAcronym[j]=userPhrase[i];
   }
   j++;
```

}

where the variable `j` is incremented in each iteration of the loop.

And calling the function `strlen` in the condition of the loop is inefficient.

Also the function does not copy only initial upper case letters of words to the destination array. It tries to copy any upper case letter. So the for loop in any case does not make a sense.

The function can be defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *  CreateAcronym( const char userPhrase[], char userAcronym[] )
{
    char *p = userAcronym;
    
    while ( *userPhrase )
    {
        while ( isspace( ( unsigned char )*userPhrase ) ) ++userPhrase;
        
        if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )*userPhrase ) ) *p++ = *userPhrase;
        
        while ( *userPhrase && !isspace( ( unsigned char )*userPhrase ) ) ++userPhrase;
    }

    *p = '\0';
    
    return userAcronym;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *phrase = "Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers";
    char acronym[10];
    
    puts( CreateAcronym( phrase, acronym ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
IEEE
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it. First, you used j++ not in "if". And second, you didnt put '\0' in your userAcronym string. '\0' means that your string end here and all string will be printed before this symbol.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAX 60

void CreateAcronym(char userPhrase[], char userAcronym[]){
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(userPhrase); i++){
        if(isupper(userPhrase[i])){
            userAcronym[j] = userPhrase[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    userAcronym[j] = '\0';
    printf("%s", userAcronym);
}

int main(){
    char phrase[MAX];
    char acronym[10];
    fgets(phrase, MAX, stdin);
    CreateAcronym(phrase, acronym);
    return 0;
}
```